# How to display the geojson polygon after 180th meridian in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, antimeridian

Like the vector grid plugin in the leaflet:
http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/demo-geojson.html
see the above example at zoom level 1 or 2

Is there any way to display geojson, not as a tile layer?